# Debug AIDL based remote service in Eclipse

Tags: android, debugging, aidl

I'm using AIDL to build a remote service that provides a few functions to client apps. I'm facing some problems in the code of the service, and I want to debug it. Unfortunately, Eclipse doesn't stop at breakpoints within the AIDL functions in the remote service.

How do I get Eclipse to stop within services that implement AIDL interface stubs?

Answer (score 0):

During the build Android automatically generates from .java file from .aidl file with the same name. I think that you should put your breakpoints there.

Comment: Your interface that is declared in the aidl file should be somewhere implemented (in java file). I think you should put your breakpoints there.

Comment: I understood what you said. But that doesn't seem to work. It doesn't stop at that point.